# EinopsError: Error while processing rearrange-reduction pattern "(b1 b2) h w c -> (b1 h) (b2 w) c"

Tags: python, einops

I'm learning the basics of einops to incorporate in my code.

```
process = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(225),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

cat = Image.open('cat.jpeg').convert('RGB')

cat = process(cat)

rearrange(cat, '(b1 b2) h w c -> (b1 h) (b2 w) c', b1=2, b2=2)
```

Raises the error:

```
EinopsError:  Error while processing rearrange-reduction pattern "(b1 b2) h w c -> (b1 h) (b2 w) c".
 Input tensor shape: torch.Size([3, 337, 225]). Additional info: {'b1': 2, 'b2': 2}.
 Expected 4 dimensions, got 3
```

The error message seems pretty obvious, since I'm specifying 4 patches the output should be of the dimensions (patches, c, h , w). However, I'm not sure where am I supposed to specify that. I went over the tutorials by einops but I still didn't really find what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Einops message is exactly right in this case: in your pattern input has 4 dimensions: '(b1 b2) h w c', but you provide a tensor with only three dimensions.

You should process a batch of 4 images and stack them to get a 4 dim tensor. Your current transformation gets 3-dim tensor (single image) and returns 3-dim tensor.

Comment: Yep, I should have come back and given the answer. I am telling it to add dimensions to height width from here it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that einops expects the batch dimension to be the first dimension by default. So, your input tensor shape `(3, 337, 225)` is not of the expected shape `(4, 3, 337, 225)`.
You can either rearrange your input tensor so that the batch dimension is the first dimension or you can specify the `batch_dim` argument to rearrange.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be the case, I thought exactly that initially and did try that already. That just raises the error to be

rearrange(cat, '(b1 b2) b h w c -> b (b1 h) (b2 w) c', b1=2, b2=2)
EinopsError:  Error while processing rearrange-reduction pattern "(b1 b2) b h w c -> b (b1 h) (b2 w) c".
 Input tensor shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 337, 225]). Additional info: {'b1': 2, 'b2': 2}.
 Expected 5 dimensions, got 4